# What does placing parenthesis alone around a function mean? (function(){})

Tags: javascript, function

I know what an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression is. I know the difference between this

```
let x = function()
{

}
```

and this

```
let x = (function()
{

})()
```

but what about this

```
let x = (function()
{

})
```

do the parenthesis here have any significance alone? I've seen it in several places before.

*[I thought this was an example but it might not be one X)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style#as-needed)*

**edit:** Those weren't really intended to be code snippets, anyhow assuming they're snippets, it turns out there's big difference between the case where they are function declarations and function expressions. I didn't expect this. Sorry for the context change and thanks for all the care!

Comment: Where is there a mention of `(function(){})` in the link you posted?

Comment: this one: `let foo = () => ({
    bar: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
    }
});` @Xufox

Comment: There has to be more to this than you've shown. As shown, the first example is a syntax error and the last example is completely pointless.

Comment: This is something _completely different_. Please state the _exact_ syntax you’re confused about.

Comment: @MinaMichael that's completely different - an arrow function returning an object literal

Comment: true but it's not different to me than this:

`let foo = (function(){
    return { bar: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
    }
}
});`

Comment: @MinaMichael Why did you interpret that arrow function as a function wrapped in parentheses? There are none wrapping the whole function in the original arrow function syntax; otherwise it would look like `let foo = (() => ({`…`}))`.

Comment: hmm I guess you're right, but the question still remains, and it's a simple one. And I've seen brackets around functions that way before in a few projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to the edited question:**

> but what about this
>
> ```
> let x = (function()
> {
>
> })
> ```

There is no purpose served by those `()` at all. That's exactly the same as:

```
let x = function()
{

}
```

---

**Answer to question embedded in comments**:

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863030/what-does-placing-brackets-alone-around-a-function-mean-function#comment78684545_45863030) you've said you actually were wondering about this:

```
let foo = () => ({ bar: { foo: 1, bar: 2, } });
```

The `()` are necessary because that's an arrow function with a *concise body* returning the result of an object initializer. But if there's a `{` immediately after the `=>`, the `{` would be the opening of a block (verbose) body instead (not the beginning of an object initializer). That's why the `()` are necessary around the expression body of the concise arrow, to disambiguate the `{`.

Note that the `()` are **not** around the function; just its body.

You can write it the way you did:

```
let foo = () => ({ bar: { foo: 1, bar: 2, } });
```

or with `{}` and `return`:

```
let foo = () => { return { bar: { foo: 1, bar: 2, } } };
```

but not:

```
let foo = () => { bar: { foo: 1, bar: 2, } }; // Wrong
```

because the `{` would be read as the beginning of a block body.

---

**Answer to [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45863030/1):**

I'm going to assume these have names, as otherwise your first example is a syntax error.

> but what about this
>
> ```
> (function()
> {
>
> })
> ```

That would be a function expression that *isn't* immediateley invoked. Unlike your first example, it's evaluated when the step-by-step execution reaches it, instead of when the context it's in is initially created.

Unless something is using the result of that expression, it's a no-op (something that does nothing), since nothing in the expression runs it.

If the result of the expression *is* being used (it's the right-hand side of an assignment, it's being passed into a function as an argument, etc.), the `()` around it are unnecessary with a `function` expression. (That isn't always the case with an arrow function.)

Answer (score 3):

Given [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45863030/1):

All else being equal (and it probably isn't because you omitted the context):

1. This is a syntax error. It starts off as a function declaration and then doesn't meet the syntax requirements.
2. This is an immediately invoked function expression.
3. The parenthesis make this a function expression (just like in example 2). It isn't invoked (the `()` are missing at the end). It isn't assigned anywhere. It does nothing.

---

But now you've rewritten the question and completely changed the meaning.

Example 3 and Example 1 are now the same.

Putting `(` and `)` around an expression does nothing except override operator precedence … and there are no operators inside them.

Comment: Well, it is. Just try it.

Comment: @MinaMichael: The first one, as shown, is. You've removed a bit too much context, I think.

Comment: @MinaMichael — It is — http://jsbin.com/piqoxiqeha/1/edit?js,console,output — but see the first sentence of this answer where I point out that you've thrown away the context.

Comment: when I run this script in node I don't get an error:

`let x = (function()
{
console.log(0)
})

x()` and I get a zero in the terminal

Comment: @MinaMichael — Well, no. You wouldn't, but (a) You put `let x =` in front of it (context!!!) and (b) That's example 3 not example 1. I said example 1 would throw a syntax error.

Comment: I see. I didn't mean it. I should have put the `let x =`. This clarifies the question. Sry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between `(function() {})` and `function() {}`.

This lines are also the same :

```
var test1 = (function() {});
var test2 = function() {};
```

BUT, if you only write this :

```
function() {};
```

You'll get a syntax error. If you don't want a syntax error you have to write this :

```
(function() {});
```

But this line is useless and do nothing at all. Because the defined function is never called and no one can access it.

Comment: Well, there is, **if** it's where a statement is expected.

Comment: oh yes, i see what you mean

Answer (score -1):

Enclosing a function in parentheses in this way lets you package it for use in another variable or function.

For example, you could use this (somewhat redundantly) to set a variable to a function.

```
var foo = (function bar() { /* code */ });
foo(); // calls code in bar()
```

This is also a way to package a callback function, e.g.

```
asyncFunction((function callback() { /* code */ });
```

You wouldn't want to use this type of declaration on its own because it becomes hidden to the rest of your code as in the below example.

```
function foo() { /* code */ };
(function bar() { /* code */ });

foo(); // runs foo code
bar(); // ERROR - bar() undefined in this scope
```

A similar syntax is used with a trailing parentheses in an "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression". This passes a variable into your function and runs it inline.

```
(function foo(a) { console.log(a) })("Hello World!");
// Prints "Hello World"
```

**TL;DR** - Use it as a way to write a named function inline and package it into another function or variable or, with trailing parentheses, to call your function immediately with a specified input.